# How can I get a more descriptive profiling report from Callgrind when using Eigen?

Tags: c++, optimization, profiling, valgrind, eigen

I'm trying to do some optimization on a program written in C++ which uses the Eigen library for matrix calculations. I've compiled the program with `g++ -pg -g main.cpp`, and I execute with `valgrind --tool=callgrind a.out` before visualizing the resulting file in kcachegrind.

What I'm seeing is that the `mcount` and `__mcount_internal` functions are taking up an extremely disproportionate amount of self-time (about 77% of the overall program time) compared to my actual code. I believe this is due to the fact that Eigen's high level of abstraction results in a bunch of deeply nested function calls which are being included in the profiling (since it's a header library). This makes it difficult to analyze the results of the profiling and determine which areas are ripe for speed-up, since I don't know how much the inclusive time of any given function is being inflated by those calls to `mcount`.

I could just sort by total self-time for all functions and skip the `mcount` lines, but all of the Eigen internal calls make this list pretty useless for analyzing the higher level program.

So my question is: is there a way to remove these (or any other) specific functions from consideration in the kcachegrind visualization, or prevent the calls to `mcount` within Eigen in the first place? Alternatively, are there other profiling workflows which are suited to deal with this issue? I would be totally satisfied with a solution that (in terms of profiling) treats Eigen as an external library and does not incur the extra profiling overhead for its internal calls.

Comment: I think you should run you program with optimization (ie. `-O3`) to profile it and have a more clear view of what is really happening (it will inline all the trivial function call of Eigen).

Comment: @JérômeRichard That's fair, I guess I wanted to have a better understanding of the expensiveness of some individual lines/calls within my functions and thought it would be best to minimize optimization for that purpose. I have a somewhat more monolithic structure than I'd prefer, so having the line numbers would be nice.

Comment: As indicated, it is recommended to use an optimised executable for callgrind. Typically, kcachegrind visualisation will still allow you to understand where the time is spent.  Also you should not combine callgrind with -pg, as  -pg introduces these  mcount heavy calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying out https://github.com/jasonrohrer/wallClockProfiler , this will return the call stacks most used. Callgrind has severe problems when it comes to "cycle detection", you could try turning that off in kcachegrind as well, and your results may (or may not) become more readable.